# Subir imagen servidor PHP MySQL - form/data

Tags: php, html, mysql, imagen

Dispongo de un formulario para subir los datos de una cabaña a una tabla llamada "cabanas" y las imagenes elegidas mediante la propiedad input "file" a la tabla "imagenes".

**El problema que tengo es que no se me suben las imagenes.** ¿Qué hago mal?

Salida por pantalla: `Ocurrió algun error al copiar el archivo.` ¡Siempre!

**Código del formulario HTML + PHP:**

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar"... 
    //Realizamos el "INSERT" antes que el "SELECT" para que se actualice la tabla correctamente.
    if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];
        //Llamamos al método "anadirCabana" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
        //Llamamos al método "insertarImagen" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        //BD::insertarImagen($idimagen, $ruta, $idcabana);

        // Comprobamos si ha ocurrido un error.
        if (!isset($_FILES["imagen"]) || $_FILES["imagen"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error.";
        }else{
            // Verificamos si el tipo de archivo es un tipo de imagen permitido.
            // y que el tamaño del archivo no exceda los 16MB
            $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
            $limite_kb = 16384;

            if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024){
                // Archivo temporal
                $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

                // Tipo de archivo
                $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];

                // Leemos el contenido del archivo temporal en binario.
                $fp = fopen($imagen_temporal, 'r+b');
                $imagen = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
                fclose($fp);

                //Podríamos utilizar también la siguiente instrucción en lugar de las 3 anteriores.
                // $imagen=file_get_contents($imagen_temporal);

                // Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
                $imagen = mysql_escape_string($imagen);

                // Insertamos en la base de datos.
                $sql = BD::anadirImagen($imagen, 4);
                if($sql==1){
                    echo "El archivo ha sido copiado exitosamente.";
                }else{
                    echo "Ocurrió algun error al copiar el archivo.";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_formulario_cabana.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ocultar_mostrar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña" /></b>
                    </font>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            /*
                            $mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();
                            */
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br/><br/><br/>
        <!-- Añadir una cabaña -->
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="anadir" id="anadir" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar_formulario_cabana();">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==1){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
                <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" />
            <br/><br/>

            <!-- Subir archivos chmod("./carpeta_upload/",755); -->
            <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
                <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" /> <!-- multiple="multiple" -->
            <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar" />
            <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código PHP en el fichero .sql llamado BD**

```
 static public function anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cabanas (nombre, capacidad, descripcion, precio) VALUES ('".$nombre."', ".$capacidad.", '".$descripcion."', ".$precio.")";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    static public function anadirImagen($ruta, $idcabana){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (ruta, idcabana) VALUES ('".$ruta."', ".$idcabana.")";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Añado captura de pantalla del valor que obtengo en "echo $imagen" para ver que me devuelve... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que envías en la variable $imagen a la función anadirImagen()? , me parece que estas enviando mal ese parámetro, seguro estas mandando un array y no la url. podrías imprimir el valor de la variable antes de enviarla para verificarlo.

Comment: Si hago un echo $imagen, antes de $sql = BD::anadirImagen($imagen, 4); me sale lo siguiente, mira la pregunta editada. Añadí captura de pantalla.

Comment: Que tipo de dato tiene tu campo ruta?, me parece que quieres guardar la imagen en la base de datos?, bueno eso no es recomendable, la imagen la debes de guardar en una carpeta en tu servidor y en la base de datos guardar la url nada mas, pero si quieres guardar la imagen, el tipo de dato de ese campo deberia ser LONGBLOB dependiendo del tamaño de la imagen, ahora si deseas guardar la url, estas enviando mal el valor de la variable $ruta.

Comment: El campo ruta de mi base de datos en la tabla "imagenes" es de tipo String/Varchar, es texto, donde se almacena el nombre de la imagen "cabana4_1.jpg", eso debería mostrarse. Si, quiero guardar la imagen en la base de datos, al menos quiero guardar el nombre de la imagen, para poderla buscar en la carpeta, todas las imagenes están en la carpeta "imagenes/nombre.jpg". Quiero guardar el NOMBRE debido a que las imagenes las tengo en una carpeta, pero quiero GUARDAR el nombre.

Comment: Ok, eso esta bien, pero no veo donde armes el nombre de la imagen, guardas el nombre y el tipo pero no lo armas, debería ser algo asi $imagen = $filename.'.'.$type; y mandas el $imagen como parámetro a la función $sql = BD::anadirImagen($imagen, 4);

Comment: He editado tu respuesta y no me funciona. Contesta a la pregunta en una "respuesta" y así puedo ver el código del cual me hablas.

Comment: La extensión la obtengo de "$tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];" pero aún así me da problemas.

Comment: verifica los permisos en la carpeta donde quieres copiar , probablemente sea eso

Comment: Ese es el problema que tengo, no sé dónde se verifican o dan permisos de escritura, en plan : chmod 755

Comment: estas ejecutando esto en el servidor?? bueno en el php.ini debes buscar donde esta la carpeta tmp de apache dar permisos de escritura y donde vas a guardar la imagen debe etener acceso el usuario www-data, por cierto estas en windows o gnu/linux?

Comment: Estoy ejecutandolo dentro de la carpeta htdocs de xampp, es decir, desde localhost. No estoy desde el servidor PHPmyadmin. ¿Qué debo hacer? Esta es la parte que menos comprendo, disculpas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69868/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-omaza1990).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes armar la variable $images con el nombre que necesitas guardar, prueba primero enviando una cadena de texto de prueba como por ejemplo "images.jpg" si lo guarda quiere decir que estas armando mal el nombre, como te comentaba no veo donde lo armas, deberia ser asi:

```
$imagen = $filename.'.'.$type;
```

Y esto lo mandas en la funcion:

```
$sql = BD::anadirImagen($imagen, 4);
```

Ahora si quieres encriptar el nombre o pasarlo a otro formato, seria sobre la variable $imagen ya con el nombre bien armado y dependiendo del formato, debes cambiar el tipo de dato del campo de tu tabla.

Comment: Ahora sí me lo agrega, el problema es que me agrega un nombre MUY extraño y largo no me guarda el nombre como "cabana4_1.jpg" sino que añade un "ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿá!æExifII*" o algo parecido.

Comment: usa  $_FILES['imagen']['name']; en lugar de  $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']; , no veo que encriptes ni que se cambie el nombre de la imagen, ese debe de ser el nombre en caso venga igual en name, imprimelo ni bien la recibes para que valides el nombre.

Comment: Cierto, debido a que tmp_name es para archivo temporal en la carpeta /xampp/tmp.

Comment: `"ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿá!æExifII*"` eso es la cabecera de un archivo jpeg (`ÿØÿàJFIF`)